# What was the largest warship sunk by a Motor Torpedo Boat in WW2?

Tags: world-war-two, naval

I know that in WW1 the Austrian battleship Szent Istvan was sunk by an Italian motor torpedo boat.  What was the largest warship sunk by a PT boat in WW2?

Comment: In the title of this question you ask about MTBs, but in the body you use the US specific term PT boat. I presume you mean to ask what was the largest ship sunk by torpedoes by fast attack boats of any nation in WW2. And by largest I take that to mean greatest full load displacement.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The loss of HMS Manchester (11,930 tons full load displacement), from the [Wikipedia article of the Manchester](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HMS_Manchester_%2815%29):

> **Sinking**
>
> Manchester took part in Operation Pedestal, an operation to supply the
>   besieged island of Malta, and which cost a number of warships,
>   including the carrier HMS Eagle. During the operation, on 13 August,
>   she was torpedoed and disabled by two Italian motor torpedo boats and
>   subsequently scuttled with explosive charges. She was the largest ship
>   sunk by motor torpedo boats during the Second World War.[1](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HMS_Manchester_%2815%29)
>
> [1](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HMS_Manchester_%2815%29) Malvezzi, Pierluigi. "MAS, VAS and MS". Regia Marina Italiana.
>   Retrieved 27 June 2013.

[image]
*Royal Navy official photographer - This is photograph FL 4159 from the collections of the Imperial War Museums (collection no. 8308-29)*

Comment: Nice idea but I like also @Pieter Geerkens 's answer because tonnage of McCawley is superior

Answer (score 0):

That is possibly [the accidental sinking of the attack transport **USS McCawley**](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/USS_McCawley_(APA-4)), Rear Admiral Richmond Kelly Turner's flagship for the invasion of Rendova Island on June 30, 1943, following her substantial damage by aerial attack and subsequent evacuation.